# No valid selected objects when baking

Tags: texture-baking, baking, error

I'm learning blender and trying the baking tool now. I'm using a very simple material with just a base color node to try out baking, but I'm getting a "No valid objects selected" error. I want to bake this base color to an image without shadows, so I'm using Diffuse Color baking type. I've tried everything I found to solve this, but nothing works. I have a mesh selected in edit mode. I have it unwrapped. I have all of it selected. I have created a blank image. I've created an Image Texture node and assigned this image to it. The Image Texture node is selected by clicking on it. The "Selected to Active" is unchecked. And I'm still getting this error. I don't know what I'm missing. Here is the screenshot:

[image]